# How to interpret an apache mod rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am struggling to fully understand this rule and want to make sure that I am not guessing.

funny.cat.pictures.com is my silly attempt to hide the clients actual 4 part url . I found this rule in a conf file in sites-enabled. It was written by others before me.

```
<Directory /var/www/active/vhost/funny.cat.pictures.com/html>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/funny\.cat\.pictures\.com/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/funny\-cat\.pictures\.com/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/all/
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
  </IfModule>
```

Am I correct to say the meaning of this rule is:
if the uri has /sites/ but 1) does not have /sites/funny[. or -]pictures.com or 2) does not have /sites/all  then block that path as a forbidden path?

Do I understand this correctly?

I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more testing confirmed that what I posed here as a question was correct.
This configuration comes handy in drupal multisite setups.
Given a site funny.cat.pictures.com all request to funny.cat.pictures.com/sites/funny.pictures.com/files/... or funny.cat.pictures.com/sites/funny-pictures.com/files/... will be allowed.
But apache will block a request to
funny.cat.pictures.com/sites/another.site.com/files/...